# Raspbian img on Pi 4: unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(179,2)

Tags: raspbian, sd-card, boot-issues, pi-4

I've just got my first Raspberry Pi 4. I'm trying to install Raspbian's July 2019 version. I've read all related issues to this problem here and I can´t manage to find the problem.

I downloaded Raspbian with desktop from the official page: https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/
And flashed it on my Kingston 32 gb Class 10 SD Card using balenaEtcher.

The first incovenient I got was the write speed I got while using balenaEtcher: between 600 and 800 kbps. When the flash finished "succesfully", a tiny warning, hidden under a red X said:

```
\.\PhysicalDrive1: Source and Destination checksums do not match
```

I didn't pay attention to this warning and proceeded to turn on my Pi anyway, and then I got the error in the title:

```
Kernel panic-not syncing: VFS: unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(179,2)
```

Reading other issues here, I tried editing **cmdline.text** by changing the rootfs and replace the 2 at the end with a 6, but this made my Pi stuck at the four raspberries without booting.

I also tried doing a filesystem check with **fsck.ext4** on my PC with Linux mint but I got a message that said that the filesystem couldn't be found.

I think that the SD Card may be the problem but I just want to make sure it is before buying a new one, as they are not cheap where I live.

I don't know what else I can do. Thanks for your help.

EDIT:

Already run an H2testw, here we have the results:

```
Warning: Only 30869 of 30870 MByte tested.
The media is likely to be defective.
87.0 MByte OK (178293 sectors)
30.0 GByte DATA LOST (63041419 sectors)
Details:36.5 KByte overwritten (73 sectors)
0.5 KByte slightly changed (< 8 bit/sector, 1 sector)
30.0 GByte corrupted (63041345 sectors)
36.5 KByte aliased memory (73 sectors)
First error at offset: 0x0000000002f41010
Expected: 0x5899e01398821110
Found: 0x5899e01398821510
H2testw version 1.3
Writing speed: 7.95 MByte/s
Reading speed: 9.72 MByte/s
H2testw v1.4
```

Don't need to make any more clarifications, already bought a new card, thanks for your time.

Comment: I have been using different types of uSD cards,  the writing speed varies from about 4Mb/s to 8/10MB/s or higher.  I never saw your ridiculously low speed.

Comment: So I should probably switch my SD Card?

Comment: yes, get two class 10+ ones.

Comment: Why 2? I've already bought a new one, I should receive it this afternoon, but why should I get 2? They are not that cheap where I live

Comment: Well, I was about to suggest to use 16GB Class 10 x 2, which I think is most cost effective, unless you are doing video/image processing things.  I always  use two cards to swap troubleshooting. You may even consider 8GB Class 10, if it is much cheaper.  Beside swap troubleshooting, it is a good idea to keep a backup copy.

Comment: Here it is not cheaper to buy 2 of 16 gb, but will consider it the next time. Thanks

Comment: I see.  So in your place 32GB is perhaps the optimum.  I forgot to let you know that I once worked in a factory and it is important for everything to have a spare part, or a second source, otherwise if the one and only one component breaks down, and there is no immediate replacement, we will be in big trouble. :)

Comment: Yes, I know. Thought I could make backups on an old HDD I have, which has a lot of free space and I use only with that purpose and is always in a safe place. All the information that is important for me is backed up somewhere. The one I don't care too much about isn't backed up, I just bought the Raspberry for entertainment only, it is not that the information there is important

Comment: I see, it would be fine if you have a HDD for backing up.  By the way, in my place, a 16GB SD card is about US$4, compare to our minimum hourly wage of about US$5. https://imgur.com/gallery/nohT0YX.  The receipt lists the barcoded serial numbers, to make sure they are not fake ones, and I forgot if is is still "life long" guarantee replacement.

Comment: That's awesome. I've just finished running h2testw and mine seemsto be fake.